# Publish with Mercurial to Public Environments

Tags: mercurial, workflow

Basically I am new to using mercurial in a small team environment. I am looking for a way (3rd party if necessary to publish my change-sets/revisions to a public staging and public live server(s).

Currently I have set up on our local ubuntu server, using wildcard DNS, a directory with folders, each folder contains a project. Inside of the folder I create another folder called "repo", this stores the local clean version of my website. Then I clone from that local folder into a custom one, do my work, and push it back into the before mentioned "repo" folder.

Next that "repo" folder connects to a 3rd party site bitbucket. That's so I can work off site.

What I want to figure it out is if there are open source or something to allow me in a web interface, see my revision and select to publish it to one of the 2 server locations. I know beanstalk can do it, but I really like bitbucket and it's cost effective. I have about 15-25 different repositories.

Is my process too much? How can I make this process the most efficient as possible.

Comment: There are lots of blogs of folks using Fabric, but none with a web UI that I know of. Interested in the findings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using hgweb?  It's not clear from your description that you are, and you certainly should be.

That aside, cloning from a central-ish repo to a local working clone, modifying, committing, and pushing bash to the central-ish repo sounds pretty normal.

Why use a web interface to push from your central-ish private repo to your public site?  Why not just go from your working clone to the public site?

For example on my local machine (not a web server at all) in the repository for my blog I have this in the `.hg/hgrc` file:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://ry4an.org/projects/unblog
publish = https://ry4an.org/hg/unblog
```

If I do `hg pull` I get changes from the private repo on my ry4an.org server in my home directory.  Then I edit, commit, and `hg push` which again goes to my private repo on my remote server.  When I want to actually publish the blog entry I do `hg push publish` which pushes the changesets from my local working repository to the public one (at http://ry4an.org/hg/unblog which is the live content for http://ry4an.org/unblog)

In theory I could use a web interface of some sort to move changesets from ssh://ry4an.org/projects/unblog to https://ry4an.org/hg/unblog, but sending them from my local working clone gives me better tools (`hg incoming`, `hg outgoing`, `hg log`, etc.)

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding your goals or was that helpful?

Comment: It was certainly helpful, I do not fully grasp everything, because I am still trying to set up a process here with a small team. I use the mac app of source tree, and I read that I can do branches for "production" "development" etc.. Can I use the app to publish to my public dev and public production servers as well as my local shared repo?

Comment: You can, but you're really better off using the command line tools until you understand what they're doing.